# Add pair lines in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have some data measured pair-wise (*e.g.* 1C, 1M, 2C and 2M), which I have plotted separately (as C and M). However, I would like to add a line between each pair (*e.g.* a line from point 1 in the C column to point 1 in the M 'column').

A small section of the entire dataset:

```
PairNumber  Type    M
1   M   0.117133
2   M   0.054298837
3   M   0.039734
4   M   0.069247069
5   M   0.043053957
1   C   0.051086898
2   C   0.075519
3   C   0.065834198
4   C   0.084632915
5   C   0.054254946
```

I have generated the below picture using the following tiny R snippet:

```
boxplot(test$M ~ test$Type)
stripchart(test$M ~ test$Type, vertical = TRUE, method="jitter", add = TRUE, col = 'blue')
```

**Current plot:**
[image]

I would like to know what command or what function I would need to achieve this (a rough sketch of the desired result, with only some of the lines, is presented below).

**Desired plot:**
[image]

**Alternatively**, doing this with ggplot is also fine by me, I have the following alternative ggplot code to produce a plot similar to the first one above:

```
ggplot(,aes(x=test$Type, y=test$M)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0))
```

I have been trying `geom_path`, but I have not found the correct syntax to achieve what I want.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data to make this reproducible? In addition, are you okay with using packages (e.g. `ggplot2`) or does this have to be implemented in base R?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I just added ggplot as a viable alternative. I will add a few example points (although not the entire set, due to size).

Comment: `boxplot(M ~ Type, dd); points(x <- jitter(as.numeric(dd$Type)), dd$M); with(dd, segments(x[Type == 'C'], M[Type == 'C'], x[Type == 'M'], M[Type == 'M']))`

Comment: You can also `ggpaired` function: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggpaired.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably recommend breaking this up into multiple visualizations -- with more data, I feel this type of plot would become difficult to interpret. In addition, I am not sure it's possible to draw the `geom_lines` and connect them with the additional call to `geom_jitter`. That being said, this gets you most of the way there:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Type, y = M)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_line(aes(group = PairNumber)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Plot]

The trick is to specify your `group` aesthetic within `geom_line()` and not up top within `ggplot()`.

*Additional Note: No reason to fully qualify your aesthetic variables within `ggplot()` -- that is, no reason to do `ggplot(data = test, aes(x = test$Type, y = test$M)`; rather, just use: `ggplot(data = test, aes(x = Type, y = M))`.*

---

**UPDATE**
Leveraging `cowplot` to visualize this data in different plots could prove helpful:

```
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Type, y = M, color = Type)) +
  geom_boxplot()

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Type, y = M, color = Type)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0))

p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = M, color = Type, fill = Type)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5)

p4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Type, y = M)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = PairNumber, color = factor(PairNumber)))

plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, labels = c(LETTERS[1:4]), align = "v")
```

[image: Cowplot Grid]

Comment: I just had a segment using geom_path and geom_jitter that was close (just the lines did not goto the jittered points). However, I like your idea using geom_line better.

Comment: @BasJansen No, there are not short lines connecting the `C` column, those are just the "whiskers" of the box plot. Consider what happens when you change the `geom_line()` to `geom_line(aes(group = PairNumber, color = factor(PairNumber)))`.

Comment: Nm, the last comment... I was suffering from a brain fart.